# Curl, post/insert null values

Tags: bash, curl

Can anyone advice what's wrong with my script?
Here it is:

```
#!/bin/sh
url="http://myhost.mydomain/test.php"
status=$(curl -s --head -w %{http_code} "$url" -o /dev/null)
while read LINE
do
#
#some stuffs here
#

if [ $status -eq 200 ]
then
    curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
    -XPOST "$url" --data '{"name":"'"$name"'","email":"'"$email"'","phone":"'"$phone"'"}'
else
    echo "Invalid Link."
done < myFile.txt
```

Please look at the actual result when I post (direct insert into db).

```
ID Name   Email                Phone
1                              0   
2  Anne   anne@example.com     112783
3  Anne2  anne2@example.com    112784
```

As you can see, it posted null value at **ID 1**. How can I avoid this kind of situation wherein no unnecessary null value/s will be added/posted in the page? Would appreciate for any help. Thanks.

Comment: [$status -eq 200] will call test.php with null value. In test.php you need to check if $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and insert nothing if $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'

Comment: I had trouble understanding @anhic's comment, although it is basically correct.  The `status` assignment is where the first PHP invocation happens, though, not when you compare the resulting status to 200.

Comment: (1) I do not understand the @anhic's comment, too. (2) A `fi` is missing. (3) Why the `if-then-else` is inside the `while` loop? If the `status` is not 200, the output will be only lines displaying `Invalid link.`

Answer (score 0):

What about just adding check, if $name and $email and $phone variables are all non-empty?

```
if [ $status -eq 200 ]
then
    if [ -n "$name$email$phone" ]
    then
        curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
        -XPOST "$url" --data '{"name":"'"$name"'","email":"'"$email"'","phone":"'"$phone"'"}'
    else
        echo "Invalid data."
    fi
else
```